# Remplazar lista en Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, python-3.7

Tengo dos lista en python como las siguientes

```
a=[1,1,1,1]
b=[-1,-1,-1,-1]
```

Quiero remplazar La lista b por el contenido de a quedando las listas de la siguiente manera

```
a=[1,1,1,1]
b=[1,1,1,1]
```

¿Hay algún método o librería que me lo permita?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ojo con Python!!!

La asignación

```
a=[1,1,1,1]
b=[-1,-1,-1,-1]
b = a
```

significa que hay **una** sola lista conteniendo cuatro elementos ([1,1,1,1]). Esta lista la puedes usar por cualquiera de los dos nombres (`a` y `b`). Entonces

```
a[0] = 5
print(a) => [5, 1, 1, 1]
print(b) => [5, 1, 1, 1]
```

modifica ambas listas, pues son una sola lista con dos nombres distintos.

Si quieres "copiar" una lista, en el sentido de obtener otra lista distinta con los mismos valores, usas el método `copy()`

```
a = [1,1,1,1]
b = [-1,-1,-1,-1]
b = a.copy()
a[0] = 5
print(a) => [5,1,1,1]
print(b) => [1,1,1,1]
```

El método `copy()` efectua una copia *superficial*: si un elemento de la lista es otra lista, diccionario, etc., el proceso de copia no se aplica recursivamente dentro de esa otra lista, diccionario, etc.

```
a=[1, ['a', 'b'], 2]
b=a.copy()
a[0] = 5
a[1][0] = 'A'
print(a) => [5, ['A', 'b'], 2]
print(b) => [1, ['A', 'b'], 2]
```

La alternativa son las copias *profundas*. Si necesitas que **toda** la lista, incluyendo **todos** sus contenidos sean copiados recursivamente, usas `deepcopy()`

```
from copy import deepcopy

a=[1, ['a', 'b'], 2]
b=deepcopy(a)
a[0] = 5
a[1][0] = 'A'
print(a) => [5, ['A', 'b'], 2]
print(b) => [1, ['a', 'b'], 2]
```

Lee la documentación oficial en [Operaciones de copia superficial y profunda](https://docs.python.org/es/3.8/library/copy.html).

Answer (score 0):

Lo puedes hacer con una asignación:

```
 b=a
```

Ejemplo:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Tu respuesta tiene un problema que es mencionado en la respuesta de Candid Moe. La asignación no crea una nueva lista, le da otro nombre a la misma.

Comment: Tienes razón, gracias por la aclaración.